obtaining objects from array but array shows empty
I was trying to write a class method to list out employee's name from google Firestore. The class is then use in other pages.

After using getDocs() to get DocumentSnapShot of the collection, the documents are all push into an array.
The array is then called from the other web page
The array shows empty, but after expanding the array there is objects inside

CustomFunction.ts
class Employee {

    private UserCollection = collection(db, "User")
    array: object[] = []

    public async getEmployees() {
        try {
            const UserDocuments = await getDocs(this.UserCollection)
            UserDocuments.forEach((docs) => {
                this.array.push(docs.data())
            })
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error message: ${error}`)
        }
        console.log(this.array)
    }

}

export const EmployeeList = Employee

EmployeeList.vue
const Employees = new EmployeeList()
let FetchUser = async () => { await Employees.getEmployees() }
FetchUser()
console.log(Employees.array)

Log shows from EmployeeList.vue:

Log shows from CustomFunction.ts:

I tried indexing both arrays, array on EmployeeList.vue shows undefined while array on CustomFunctions.ts did give me the object I had indexed.
May I know why the array in EmployeeList.vue is empty?

It needs to await the result of FetchUser

As Tim commented, you'll need to await FetchUser(). Without that, your console.log(Employees.array) runs before the asynchronous call has completed.
If dealing with asynchronous calls in JavaScript is new for you, I recommend checking out the MDN documentation on Asynchronous JavaScript.
